# Where does this O-ring belong on this Blue microphone?

Tags: microphones, stand

I recently took my Blue 888--000322 off of a normal mic stand and re-installed it on its desktop stand (which came packaged with it).  When I was done, I found this tiny o-ring on my desk.  Where does it belong?  Next to the microphone, there is a specially-shaped washer, then the stand itself; on the other side you can see 2-3 small round washers.  This o-ring must go somewhere in there, yes?

I suppose I could take apart the other side and look for the matching o-ring, but the design of the stand makes it hard to do this without the washers falling off.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ELHL.jpg)
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the contour of the contoured washer (usually called a "saddle washer") mates snugly with the barrel of the microphone (as it seems to), I would assume they are meant to contact directly, without the O-ring.  The most likely place then for the O-ring is between the saddle washer and stand where it will keep the mic from tilting, even without having the nuts really tight.

Comment: This seems to be a likely case.  I tried it and having the O-ring between the stand and the contoured washer helps keep the contoured washer in its place on the microphone body.  Without it, it spins out of alignment.

Answer (score 2):

I guess between 'contoured washer' and mic body. Shoud be a matching one the other side.

Comment: I didn't see one there (I probably lost that one already!  Thanks tho.

Comment: Boxes of mixed o-rings are cheap, and handy once in a while - this sounds like that while...